# How to prevent tabs from updating / re-rendering when they are not focused?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using material top tabs. Problem is, when a state changes in one tab, all other tabs that use the same state render again which slows the app a little. How do I prevent tabs from getting updated unless they are focused / seen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your components, you can get `state` property and detect is it in focus or not. And if it is not in focus you can prevent rerendering or place your own logic. An example is here:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator#tabbar

Comment: Thanks. The useIsFocused hook solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TabNavigator.Navigator
  // set lazy true to prevent pre-render
  lazy={true}
  optimizationsEnabled={true}
  tabBarOptions={tabBarOptions}>
    <TabNavigator.Screen name="HOME" component={HOME} />
    <TabNavigator.Screen name="SHOP" component={SHOP} />
</TabNavigator.Navigator>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without lazy loading? This creates an even bigger problem. Isn't there an onFocused or something like this for tabs?